Receiving mails from Drupal but not from CiviCRM for one contact
A few weeks ago a CiviCRM installation stopped sending mail to my address and all other emailaddresses on my domain. These contacts are not 'on hold'. The logs and activities are saying the mail is sent, and no errors.
On the same server, Drupal is sending emails to me just fine, so I don't think it is the hosting provider blocking outgoing mails to my domain; unless both system use a different mail transport ?
I'm sure the receiving server (mine) is not removing messages without notifying me. My server could reject the incoming mail, but why would it only reject mails from Civi and not from Drupal ? Or likewise, the delivering server could refuse to deliver to my server, but why only Civi mails and not Drupal mails ?
Outgoing mail from civi to other domains I tested seem to be received just fine.
How would I go about debugging this ?

Can you say a bit more about your mail configuration?  E.g. what are your settings on Administer » System Settings » Outgoing Email?  Are you using mail() or SMTP there?  Or perhaps you're using an extension like Sparkpost?  If you're using SMTP, is it a commercial provider (e.g. smtp.gmail.com) or a server you control?

Depending on your mail provider, you may be able to do a meage trace to find out if it has been rejected by your server, and if it has, it would normally state why.
It could be that CIVI is using the VERP and drupal isnt which is another reason why this isn't working. If this is the case you can disable VERP in CIVI as detailed in another question in SE.
Hope this helps
